# What is the optimal sampling rate / window size for Word2Vec Continuous Bag of Words?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec

What is the greatest number of embeddings you can average for the Word2Vec Cbow algorithm before measures of quality start dropping?

For skip-gram I've seen window sizes up to 20 work, but I imagine this range may be lower for Cbow since the embeddings are averaged, which may make for difficult optimization.

Comment: Is this a question about window size or about dataset size? AFAIK you don't typically choose the number of embeddings to average; you just average across all appearances of the word in question.

Comment: The question is about the number of randomly selected word embeddings to average within a window size. I'm not asking anything about dataset size.

Comment: To my knowledge, in standard CBOW you don't average the embeddings within the window. In CBOW as I know it, you use a fixed window, and you try to predict the word in the center of the window. Then, to get the vector for a particular word, you take the average predicted vector across all appearances of the word. If this is a more advanced technique, it might be helpful to include a link to a reference, since i can't find any in a quick search and I've never heard of it before.

Comment: http://mccormickml.com/assets/word2vec/Alex_Minnaar_Word2Vec_Tutorial_Part_II_The_Continuous_Bag-of-Words_Model.pdf pages 2-3

Comment: I see. *That* average is just the action of the hidden layer. Matrix multiplication is a form of weighted average. You are asking about the window size. The embeddings themselves are not averaged in the way you're suggesting.

Comment: From the PDF it looks like the embeddings are averaged across the dimensions of the embeddings, is it something else? I'm trying to figure out if there are any studies on relationship between number of embeddings averaged and quality of the resulting embeddings.

Comment: A CBOW context enters the model as a large, sparse binary matrix $x_i$. The hidden layer contains a matrix of weights, $W$. $i$ indexes observations in the data set. The output for the hidden layer is $\frac{1}{C} \sum_i W x_i$. Every neural network does something similar. The matrix product of $W$ and $x_i$ is a sort of average of the $x_{i}$s, weighted by the elements of $W$. This is an average over individual word appearances in the context. This has nothing to do with averaging over embeddings, which is a different step.